# Python - Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, i have a dict like below

```
{'key1': [L1, L2],
 'key2': [P1, P2],
 'key3': [T1],
 'key4': [V1]}
```

The desired output is

```
{'key1': [L1], 'key2': [P1], 'key3': [T1], 'key4': [V1]},
{'key1': [L2], 'key2': [P2], 'key3': [T1], 'key4': [V1]}
```

Any assistance!

Comment: **what did you try?**

Comment: print "{'key1': [L1], 'key2': [P1], 'key3': [T1], 'key4': [V1]},\n{'key1': [L2], 'key2': [P2], 'key3': [T1], 'key4': [V1]}" satisfies your stated criteria. Could you be more explicit in your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: d = {'key1': ['L1', 'L2'],  
 'key2': ['P1', 'P2'],
 'key3': ['T1'],
 'key4': ['V1']}

In [2]: [{k: [v[min(i, len(v)-1)]] for k, v in d.items()}
     for i in range(max(map(len, d.values())))]
Out[2]: 
[{'key1': ['L1'], 'key2': ['P1'], 'key3': ['T1'], 'key4': ['V1']},
 {'key1': ['L2'], 'key2': ['P2'], 'key3': ['T1'], 'key4': ['V1']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> # Let's suppose your dictionary looks something like
>>> some_dict = {'key1': ['L1', 'L2'],
 'key2': ['P1', 'P2'],
 'key3': ['T1'],
 'key4': ['V1']}
>>> #First determine the longest value sequence
>>> max_len = len(max(some_dict.values(), key = len))
>>> #assimilate your tools
>>> from itertools import izip, cycle, islice
>>> #Create the value sequence
>>> value = islice(izip(*(cycle(e) for e in some_dict.values())), max_len)
>>> #recreate the dictionary
>>> [dict(izip(some_dict.keys(), e)) for e in value]
[{'key3': 'T1', 'key2': 'P1', 'key1': 'L1', 'key4': 'V1'}, {'key3': 'T1', 'key2': 'P2', 'key1': 'L2', 'key4': 'V1'}]
>>>
```

**Note**, in case the order matters, use an `OrderedDict` instead of the built-in dict.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get exactly what you wanted because I'm not sure why you would need a copy of `['T1']` or `['V1']` again:

```
d = {'key1': ['L1', 'L2'],
 'key2': ['P1', 'P2'],
 'key3': ['T1'],
 'key4': ['V1']}
print [{key:d[key][i] for key in d.keys() for i in range(len(d[key]))}, {key:d[key][i] for key in d.keys() for i in range(len(d[key])-1)}]
```

Results in:

```
[{'key3': 'T1', 'key2': 'P2', 'key1': 'L2', 'key4': 'V1'}, {'key2': 'P1', 'key1': 'L1'}]
```